# Push the values to new ViewController when a cell is tapped

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, plist

I have table view that populated with plist called "Htgg".
I am trying to push the value to a new view called "DetailViewController".

This is the code:

```
#import "Glist.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation Glist
@synthesize htgg,detailViewController;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"ofek", @"ofek");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"איך להוציא גימלים?";
    NSString *htggFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Htgg" ofType:@"plist"];
    htgg = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: htggFile];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [htgg count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }


    id keys = [htgg allKeys];


    //Get all the keys in the first dictionary (the keys are: "good", "funny", "New - Item 3")
    //This is an array, so you can do this: array[0] (in C#)

    //Here we tell the tableview cell. to put in the text - [keys objectsAtIndex:indexPath.row]; if the row is 0, we will get: "good", if 1, we will get "funny"
    cell.textLabel.text = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *showPickedSolution = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:showPickedSolution animated:YES];


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
@end
```

The code works perfect but it doesn't push the value of the row( all the rows of plist are string type and above the there is 'Root').

I need your help to push the value to another view(DetailViewController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a property in your `DetailViewController` of the same type as of your data you want to push then use

```
DetailViewController *showPickedSolution = [[DetailViewController alloc]  
 initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 showPickedSolution.yourPropertName = [htgg objectAt:indexPath.Row];      

[self.navigationController pushViewController:showPickedSolution animated:YES];
```

you can now access the passed dat in your  `DetailViewController` in your property.

Please check the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can made an `NSString` property in class `DetailViewController` and set that property in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Here is the code for your reference:

```
showPickedSolution.valueToBeSent = [htgg valueForKey:[[htgg allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

You can use this `valueToBeSent` in your `DetailViewController` class.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in two different way depending on the scenario:

1) Delegate, when I fill some values on a form that I want to pass back to the original screen.

2) Storyboard Segue, when I want to send some value(s) to a second screen.

I usually put all the values I want in an array to send the object and then at arrival I extract what I need.

Instead of explaining each way, I can refer you to [Getting Started](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started) section of the iOS Dev Site.

I hope it help!